# Unable to create/start local cluster on Windows 7 machine

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We have windows 7 with VS 2015 Update 3 and Service Fabric Runtime 6.1.456.9494 installed along with Service Fabric SDK 3.0.456. There are no errors while installing either the runtime or sdk, but still while setting up local cluster it fails with following errors, and this is happening in all the machines we are using.

> WARNING: Service Fabric Cluster is taking longer than expected to
>   connect.
>
> Waiting for Naming Service to be ready. This may take a few minutes...
>
> Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable,
>   please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue. At
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service
>   Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:620 char:12 +
>   [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @connparams) +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricClus 2> ter],
>   FabricException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFa 2>
>   bric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

**Faulting application name: Fabric.exe, version: 6.1.456.9494, time stamp: 0x5a66710e
Faulting module name: FabricCommon.dll_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a666cec 
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000007febd3e6d31
Faulting process id: 0x2854
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3a64824f31fdc
Faulting application path: C:\SfDevCluster\Data_Node_0\Fabric\Fabric.Code\Fabric.exe
Faulting module path: FabricCommon.dll
Report Id: 62dd8dbf-123b-11e8-bbb0-00505699504f**

I don't see anything useful in Trace logs either.

I tried resintalling **microsoft visual c++ 2012 redistributable package (x64)** , tried running cleanupfabric , cleanupcluster but still the issue persists.
Also unisntalled and reinstalled service fabric runtime and sdk multiple times, still issue persists.

Comment: Do you have any firewalls/anti-virus scanners installed?  Try disabling them temporarily and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I have this same issue as does an associate, this is after the latest VS 2017 15.5.6 (Fabric 2.0 tools) and the latest 3.0 SF SDK and 6.4.456 run times

Comment: @wchoward How did you resolve this issue?I am currently facing same issue